# How can I display posts (thumbnails) of specific category in different divs?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

My WordPress `front-page.php` should display all posts of my custom post category (called "archive") in an asymmetrical grid-layout. The code for the grid-layout is the following:

```css
#sec_archiv {
height: auto;
min-height: calc(100vh - 24vw);
display: -webkit-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
-webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
        flex-direction: column;
-webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
        justify-content: center;
padding: 12vw 8vw;
}

#sec_archiv .archiv_container {
display: -ms-grid;
display: grid;
-ms-grid-columns: (7vw)[12];
    grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 7vw);
-ms-grid-rows: (7vw)[17];
    grid-template-rows: repeat(17, 7vw);
grid-gap: 0;
height: auto;
width: 100%;
}

#sec_archiv .bild_container:nth-of-type(1) {
-ms-grid-row: 1;
-ms-grid-row-span: 3;
-ms-grid-column: 3;
-ms-grid-column-span: 4;
grid-area: 1 / 3 / 4 / 7;
}

#sec_archiv .bild_container:nth-of-type(2) {
-ms-grid-row: 2;
-ms-grid-row-span: 5;
-ms-grid-column: 7;
-ms-grid-column-span: 4;
grid-area: 2 / 7 / 7 / 11;
}

#sec_archiv .bild_container:nth-of-type(3) {
-ms-grid-row: 4;
-ms-grid-row-span: 4;
-ms-grid-column: 1;
-ms-grid-column-span: 6;
grid-area: 4 / 1 / 8 / 7;
}

#sec_archiv .bild_container:nth-of-type(4) {
-ms-grid-row: 7;
-ms-grid-row-span: 4;
-ms-grid-column: 7;
-ms-grid-column-span: 6;
grid-area: 7 / 7 / 11 / 13;
}

#sec_archiv .bild_container:nth-of-type(5) {
-ms-grid-row: 8;
-ms-grid-row-span: 5;
-ms-grid-column: 3;
-ms-grid-column-span: 4;
grid-area: 8 / 3 / 13 / 7;
}

#sec_archiv .bild_container:nth-of-type(6) {
-ms-grid-row: 11;
-ms-grid-row-span: 3;
-ms-grid-column: 7;
-ms-grid-column-span: 4;
grid-area: 11 / 7 / 14 / 11;
}

#sec_archiv .bild_container:nth-of-type(7) {
-ms-grid-row: 13;
-ms-grid-row-span: 4;
-ms-grid-column: 1;
-ms-grid-column-span: 6;
grid-area: 13 / 1 / 17 / 7;
}

#sec_archiv .bild_container:nth-of-type(8) {
-ms-grid-row: 14;
-ms-grid-row-span: 4;
-ms-grid-column: 7;
-ms-grid-column-span: 6;
grid-area: 14 / 7 / 18 / 13;
}

.bild_container {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: #bde535;
overflow: hidden;
}


.bilder {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
-o-object-fit: cover;
    object-fit: cover;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<section id="sec_archiv">
    <div class="archiv_container">
            <div class="bild_container" id="bild_container_eins">
 
                <a href="[link to first post]"><img class="bilder" id="bild1" src="[thumbnail of first post]" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <div class="bild_container" id="bild_container_zwei">
                <a href="[link to second post]"><img class="bilder" src="[thumbnail of second post]" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <div class="bild_container" id="bild_container_drei">
                <a href="#"><img class="bilder" src="img/musik.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <div class="bild_container" id="bild_container_vier">
                <a href="#"><img class="bilder" src="img/haus.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <div class="bild_container" id="bild_container_fünf">
                <a href="#"><img class="bilder" src="img/stoff.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <div class="bild_container" id="bild_container_sechs"></div>
            <div class="bild_container" id="bild_container_sieben"></div>
            <div class="bild_container" id="bild_container_acht"></div>
    </div>
</section>
```

I have difficulties figuring out where to add the php-code required for the WordPress-Loop and how to display the posts chronologically in those specific divs ('bild_container'). The only information I want to pull from the database is the post thumbnail (placed in those divs) and the post link — without repetition.

I assume is has something to do with pagination, but as I am now very familiar with php all help is very appreciated.

So far I have this:

```
<section id="sec_archiv">
    <div class="archiv_container">


    <!-- FIRST POST -->
        <?php
            $temp = $wp_query; $wp_query= null;
            $wp_query = new WP_Query(); $wp_query->query('posts_per_page=1' . '&paged=1');
            while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

            <div class="bild_container" id="bild_container_eins">
            
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img class="bilder" id="bild1" src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" alt=""></a>
            </div>


        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </div> 
</section>
```

Unfortunately, I get ALL posts displayed. But I only require the ones in category 'archive'.

Comment: there's going to be some php code involved, you can use this as a starting point https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/

Comment: Thanks for the link, I edited the inquiry above according to what I've learned so far.

Comment: you need to add the category argument filter in `WP_Query` so that youonly get what you actually need. it's already in the link i provided (in parameters section) https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/#parameters

Comment: I tried a few different things, but I didn't successfully filtered the posts. Where do I have to place the `array( 'category_name' => 'archive' )`? I tried it like this: `$wp_query = new WP_Query( array( 'category_name' => 'archive' ) );`